# Что не так в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Почему не работает регулярка?

```
Elapsed\sTime:\D+(.+?)<\/font>[\n]*.Last\sCalled\sNumber:\D+(\d{5,})@gw0<\/font>\D+(\d{5,})<\/font>

Elapsed Time:</td><td><font color="darkblue">16 days and 12:42:31</font><>
<>
<><>
<>
<>7gt757tLast Called Number:</td><td>
<font color="darkblue">67678799989@gw0</font>
</td><td>Last Caller Number:</td>
<td><font color="darkblue">876868856454</font>
```

Между `</font> и Last Called Number:` может быть любой текст и любое количество переносов строки (/n).
Ожидаемый результат:

```
16 days and 12:42:31
67678799989
876868856454
```

Comment: Писать обычный пробел. Или не писать ничего, `.` матчит и пробелы тоже.

Comment: вообще просто `.*` должна справится. но если вы таким образом пытаетесь сказать, что не менее N пробелов, в перемешку с другими символами, то можно `(\s.*){N}` где N количество повторов (так же это на 1 нумерацию последующих скобок подвинет)

Comment: Всё зависит от того, что это выражение должно найти, каковы требования (спецификация) к шаблону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если реализовать через замену, что-то такое должно быть:

```
^.*?<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>(.|\r|\n)*?<font.*?>(.*?)\@.*?<\/font>(.|\r|\n)*?<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>$
```

в первых, третьих и пятых скобках нужные данные.

Псевдокодом так:

```
string txt = '
Elapsed Time:</td><td><font color="darkblue">16 days and 12:42:31</font><>
<>
<><>
<>
<>7gt757tLast Called Number:</td><td>
<font color="darkblue">67678799989@gw0</font>
</td><td>Last Caller Number:</td>
<td><font color="darkblue">876868856454</font>';

print regRepace(/^.*?<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>(.|\r|\n)*?<font.*?>(.*?)\@.*?<\/font>(.|\r|\n)*?<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>$/, \1\r\n\3\r\n\5);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде работает, но как избавиться от group 2 и group 4 https://regex101.com/r/ya5LGs/1/

Comment: А зачем, если их можно тупо не юзать: https://onlinegdb.com/SZJArNcUC